# Incorrect display of multiple boxplot in one graph

Tags: r, boxplot

I expected to see all boxplots will be overlayed at 25, 85 and 125 on x axis but they were not.  Please run the code to replicate, I can't attach the image.  Thank you so much.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("plyr")

df<-data.frame(T = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 85, 85, 85, 125, 125, 125), V =c(1.03, 1.06, 1.1,1.08,1.87,1.56,1.75,1.82, 1.85, 1.90), type=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2))
df1<-data.frame(T = c(25, 25,25,85, 85, 85, 85, 125, 125,125), V =c(1.13, 1.24,1.3,1.17, 1.66,1.76,1.89, 1.90, 1.95,1.97), type=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5))
df2<-data.frame(T = c(25, 25, 25, 85, 85,85,125, 125,125), V =c(1.03, 1.06, 1.56,1.75,1.68,1.71,1.82, 1.85,1.88), type=c(7,7,7,7,7,7))

main <- rbind(df,df1,df2)
main$type <- as.factor(main$type)

main <- transform(main, type = revalue(type,c("2"="type2", "5"="type5", "7" = "type7")))

main$T <- as.factor(main$T)
ggplot(main, aes(T, V))+geom_boxplot(width=0.5/length(unique(main$type)),aes(color=type),size=.3)
```

Comment: What were you expecting? What did you want? The output from the code (with some adjustments, because `df`, `df1`, and `df2` needed some handling) seems like exactly what you'd want.

Comment: Hi Steven,  there are three different data set at 25, 85 and 125 so I expected to see three boxplot which are overlaped at 25, 85 and 125 for each data set.  Thanks.

Comment: Your code has lots of errors, fix it first please.

Comment: Hi jaySf, please show me where are the errors ?

Comment: Running all three `data.frame()` lines fails.

Comment: As Steven said, your code seems to create (after fix the errors in the dataframe creation) the plot you are looking for. 
You can add `position = 'identity'` within the `geom_boxplot()` function if you want the boxplots overlap.

Comment: @jaySf, I may have a problem with format when I posted it.  Thanks to Steven has corrected the format.  You said "lots of errors", I rerun again without any errors.  I am using RStudio version 1.1.383, I don't know what is your version.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi demarsylvain, I have added the position = 'identity' within the geom_boxplot() and I got an error "2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1".  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make some changes to your dfs. 
a) Not all variables have the same length.
b) Do not name a variable as T, it might confuse R with Boolean TRUE.

So maybe what you want is the following?

```
df<-data.frame(U = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 85, 85, 85, 125, 125), 
               V =c(1.03, 1.06, 1.1,1.08,1.87,1.56,1.75,1.82, 1.85, 1.90), type=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)) 

df1<-data.frame(U = c(25, 25,25,85, 85, 85, 85, 125, 125,125), 
                V =c(1.13, 1.24,1.3,1.17, 1.66,1.76,1.89, 1.90, 1.95,1.97), type=c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)) 

df2<-data.frame(U = c(25, 25, 25, 85, 85,85,125, 125,125), 
                V =c(1.03, 1.06, 1.56,1.75,1.68,1.71,1.82, 1.85,1.88), type=c(7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7))

main <- rbind(df,df1,df2) 
main$type <- as.factor(main$type)

main <- transform(main, type = revalue(type,c("2"="type2", "5"="type5", "7" = "type7")))

main$U <- as.factor(main$U) 

ggplot(main, aes(U, V,color=type))+geom_boxplot(width=0.5/length(unique(main$type)),size=.3,position="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Antonis, that is the plot I expected.

Comment: You're welcome Peter H. In case you found my answer helpful you may consider accepting it: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.